# Test failed in CI: "Capybara::ElementNotFound: Unable to find css"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unit-testing, continuous-integration, capybara

I was running a bunch of unit and integration tests in my Continuous Integration server (I use TeamCity) and I'm trying to know why one of my integration tests fails.

I read the stacktrace of this test and i found the following:

```
Capybara::ElementNotFound: Unable to find css "section.product[data-id=\"484802314\"]"

Stack trace:
test/integration/main_page_test.rb:7:in `pod'
    test/integration/main_page_test.rb:99:in `block in <class:MainPageTest>'
    test-unit (2.5.0) lib/test/unit/ui/testrunnermediator.rb:44:in `block in run'
    test-unit (2.5.0) lib/test/unit/ui/testrunnermediator.rb:89:in `with_listener'
    test-unit (2.5.0) lib/test/unit/ui/testrunnermediator.rb:39:in `run'
    test-unit (2.5.0) lib/test/unit/autorunner.rb:378:in `block in run'
    test-unit (2.5.0) lib/test/unit/autorunner.rb:434:in `change_work_directory'
    test-unit (2.5.0) lib/test/unit/autorunner.rb:377:in `run'
    test-unit (2.5.0) lib/test/unit/autorunner.rb:58:in `run'
```

Developers claims that this integration test runs perfectly in their machines, So, How can I override this issue?

UPDATE:

Another test that is failing is this one, i'm not sure if is related or causing the other test to fail:

MainPageTest.test_Pod_are_created_correctly:

```
Wrong number of product pods generated.
<false> is not true.

Stack trace:
test/integration/main_page_test.rb:63:in `block in <class:MainPageTest>'
    test-unit (2.5.0) lib/test/unit/ui/testrunnermediator.rb:44:in `block in run'
    test-unit (2.5.0) lib/test/unit/ui/testrunnermediator.rb:89:in `with_listener'
    test-unit (2.5.0) lib/test/unit/ui/testrunnermediator.rb:39:in `run'
    test-unit (2.5.0) lib/test/unit/autorunner.rb:378:in `block in run'
    test-unit (2.5.0) lib/test/unit/autorunner.rb:434:in `change_work_directory'
    test-unit (2.5.0) lib/test/unit/autorunner.rb:377:in `run'
    test-unit (2.5.0) lib/test/unit/autorunner.rb:58:in `run'
```

Answer (score 0):

There is not enough information to figure this out. I can make a bunch of wild guesses, but they would not be very useful. Are you sure the environments on the dev's machines and the CI are the same (versions of Ruby, gems, dependencies)? And how do you run the tests on CI?

Comment: Dev machines and CI environments are not the same. Dev machines are using MacOS X 10.7, and in CI I'm using CentOS 5.7. What information need to check to figure out this problem?

Comment: We are using the same version of Ruby, installed all the required gems and dependences.

Comment: Well, I'm afraid I cannot help you with this information. It's a rather generic test failure and it is in no way indicative of what the problem might really be. It can be a really vast array of things. I suggest having the developers debug it, since they should have the necessary knowledge of how those tests run.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that your problem may well be located within your

```
MainPageTest.test_Pod_are_created_correctly
```

Test - If this is not populating your database correctly then the original issue would be caused as by the looks of your selector "484802314" is an ID of a row within your database.

however like @Stefan Kanev mentioned within his answer, there is not enough information provided to be able to give an accurate answer.